# How to invoke a custom callback function in Javascript

Tags: theming, 8, forms, hooks, ajax

I am trying to just invoke callback in my AJAX response.

Currently I have the following response.

```
   private function responseWithSuccess($message, $status_code = 200)
    {
        $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
        $ajax_response->setStatusCode($status_code);
        $response =
            [
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => $message
            ];

        $ajax_response->setContent(\GuzzleHttp\json_encode($response));
        return $ajax_response;
    }
```

It returns a response of the specified format, but is it possible to listen for the response text in this case ?

I've found that I have to use the Drupal Command class that is used for communication.

So I created the custom Command, here is code

```
class CustomCallbackCommand implements CommandInterface, CommandWithAttachedAssetsInterface
{
    use CommandWithAttachedAssetsTrait;
    /**
     * The content for the dialog.
     */
    protected $message;


    /**
     * Constructs a \Drupal\mymodule\Ajax\BootstrapModalCommand object.
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return array(
            'command' => 'onCustomCallback',
            'message' => $this->message,
        );
    }
}
```

And add it to response like that

```
private function responseWithSuccess($message, $status_code = 200)
{
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $ajax_response->setStatusCode($status_code);
    $response =
        [
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => $message
        ];
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new CustomCallbackCommand($response));
    //$ajax_response->setContent(\GuzzleHttp\json_encode($response));
    return $ajax_response;
}
```

But when I try to send the request, an error appears.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getLibraries() on null in
>   /public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Ajax/AjaxResponse.php on line 48

What is wrong with my code ?

So basically the main question is how to call specific callback when a response comes back.

P.S.

I know that I could just override default handlers of the Drupal JS module, but I am looking for a better way.

Comment: Please paste the full error.

Comment: Any reason you are attaching assets? This is a good tutorial for AJAX commands (which works - I've made plenty): https://www.mike-miles.com/blog/creating-ajax-callback-commands-drupal-8

Comment: I am not attaching any assets, all code I have I posted above)

Comment: @Kevin, haha my bad) This is the result of copy  & paste, I copied someone else's code and didn't noticed this interface

Comment: @Kevin please post your comment as an answer for the question, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For very basic Commands, you likely do not need to implement `CommandWithAttachedAssetsInterface` or `CommandWithAttachedAssetsTrait`.

Here is a good blog post tutorial for a custom Command: https://www.mike-miles.com/blog/creating-ajax-callback-commands-drupal-8

Here is another example: https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/loading-and-rendering-modal-forms-drupal-8

Here are a couple modules that implement Commands for an example:

- [iGrowl](https://www.drupal.org/project/igrowl)
- [SweetAlert](https://www.drupal.org/project/sweetalert)

You are not going to want to override core Drupal JS, as it is easy to add your own and communicate to your plugins or third party plugins as demonstrated above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for additional information and examples, appreciate it. Have a great day !

Comment: For reference, I pasted a second example that uses OpenModalDialogCommand, which is an example of when CommandWithAttachedAssetsInterface comes in to play. See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Ajax!OpenModalDialogCommand.php/class/OpenModalDialogCommand/8.2.x