# Start form as modal, from the controller

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I see a lot of examples of modal forms. But in all these example the modal is started from a current form. There is always a link-button involved. I would like to start a form as a modal from the controller by using:

`$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formId);
return $form;`

Can someone give me an example of which extra code is needed to show the form ($formId) as a modal??

Comment: MediaCurrent just posted about this. Everything you should need is here: https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/loading-and-rendering-modal-forms-drupal-8

Comment: You could, but you need some sort of trigger to hit a callback. That callback will return an AjaxResponse instead of the standard response from a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem: in stead of a modal I use an overlay which reports a message.

My question seemed a bit theoretical, but in the Mediator Design Pattern I use, I want to solve my problems generically. In the main program I can decode when a form takes long time, before I render the form I attach extra JS which is coupled to the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

I did an example of this a while ago. Basically I defined a route, and that controller returned an [AjaxResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Ajax!AjaxResponse.php/class/AjaxResponse/8.2.x):

```
mymodule.growl:
  path: '/mymodule/growl'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::growl'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Basic controller:

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\igrowl\Ajax\GrowlCommand;

class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase {
  public function growl() {
    $options = GrowlCommand::defaultOptions();
    $options['message'] = 'This is a message.';
    $options['title'] = 'Hello';
    $options['icon'] = 'feather-check';
    $options['type'] = 'success';

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new GrowlCommand($options));
    return $response;
  }
}
```

Any link hitting that route fired that Command. So, anytime someone clicks a link going to your defined route, it should create a modal.

You basically want to return a form (use the form builder service provided by [ControllerBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Controller!ControllerBase.php/class/ControllerBase/8.2.x) instead of the static container) and at a basic level, use [OpenModalDialogCommand](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Ajax!OpenModalDialogCommand.php/class/OpenModalDialogCommand/8.2.x) (or [supply your own modal js with custom Command](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231408/how-to-invoke-a-custom-callback-function-in-javascript)). [AjaxResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Ajax!AjaxResponse.php/class/AjaxResponse/8.2.x) will take care of the rest.

Comment: Installed iGrowl but did not get it working. I get a pop-up with just a list of the options

Comment: I found the iGrowl module and installed it, but the module does not pace up with the changed structure in iGrowl.zip. I also do not know how to add the libraries and which, while they are already loaded in the Drupal module itself.

Comment: Any way we can trigger a modal from twig? I have a controller that returns the AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

You can force any link to open in a modal dialog.
Just add the class `use-ajax` and the attribute `data-dialog="modal"` to a link.

```
<a href="/node" class="use-ajax" data-dialog="modal">node list</a>
```

P.S.
Drupal uses JavaScript to apply this behavior, so make sure set the class and attribute in the server side (template/preproces/pre-render...)